# Comprehend pause and resume animation on a layer

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, core-animation, calayer

I am studying Animation in Core Animation Programming Guide and I get stuck on comprehending pause and resume animation on a layer.

The document tells me how to pause and resume animation without clear explanation. I think the key is to understand what is `timeOffset` and `beginTime` method of `CAlayer`.

These code is pause and resume animation. In `resumeLayer` method, `layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;` this line really make me confused.

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer {
   CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
   layer.speed = 0.0;
   layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer {
   CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
   layer.speed = 1.0;
   layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
   layer.beginTime = 0.0;
   CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
   layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the CAMediaTiming Protocol Ref? [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004511-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: @Bamsworld Thank you for the link. I have seen it but what it says is ambiguous.

Comment: Okay, what about this one? [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html) Animation Types and Timing Programming Guide (I think this is quite comprehensive. It explains timing and time spaces.)

Comment: @Bamsworld I have seen it but it don't help. Thank you all the same.

Comment: [This article](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/) will really help you understand animation timing

Comment: @Alladinian +1, it is useful and help me understand the `timeOffset` but I still get confused something in `resumeLayer` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the header file of CAMediaTiming, we can see these codes:

```
/* The begin time of the object, in relation to its parent object, if
 * applicable. Defaults to 0. */

@property CFTimeInterval beginTime;

/* The basic duration of the object. Defaults to 0. */

@property CFTimeInterval duration;

/* The rate of the layer. Used to scale parent time to local time, e.g.
 * if rate is 2, local time progresses twice as fast as parent time.
 * Defaults to 1. */

@property float speed;

/* Additional offset in active local time. i.e. to convert from parent
 * time tp to active local time t: t = (tp - begin) * speed + offset.
 * One use of this is to "pause" a layer by setting `speed' to zero and
 * `offset' to a suitable value. Defaults to 0. */

@property CFTimeInterval timeOffset;
```

What important is the formula:

**t = (tp - begin) * speed + offset**

This formula defines how the global time (or parent time, tp) maps to the local time of the layer. And this formula can explain everything of the listed codes:

1. At time A, the animation is paused. After sets the speed = 0, and timeOffset = pauseTime, the local time of the layer is equal pauseTime. And local time will not increase any more because speed = 0;
2. At time B, the animation is resumed. After sets the speed = 1.0, timeOffset = 0, beginTime = 0, the layer's local time is equal to the global time (or tp) which is (timePause + timeSinacePause). But we need the animation starts from the time point #A, so we set the beginTime = timeSincePaused, and then the layer's local time is equal to timePause. Of cause, this incurs the animation continue from the point paused.

[image]

Comment: Great, this is what I am waiting for! I think when we add an animation to a layer, the layer keeps the start and end local time. Then as its super time(tp) increases, the animation animates. `layer.beginTime = 0.0;` is used to restore the layer's local time related state before calling `CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];` in `pauseLayer` method.

Comment: BTW, what tool do you use to draw the diagram?

Comment: @KudoCC It's just Microsoft Excel:)

Answer (score 23):

**Let's have a test at the two properties of a layer: `beginTime` and `timeOffset`.**

**Prerequisite**

We get the CALayer's time space using `[layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]`

1、Assign 5.0 to layer's `beginTime` (`beginTime` is 0 before) :

```
NSLog(@"CACurrentMediaTime:%f", [t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
t1.layer.beginTime = 5.0 ;
NSLog(@"CACurrentMediaTime:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
```

result log is:

```
2014-01-15 11:00:33.811 newUserInterface[1404:70b] CACurrentMediaTime:7206.884498
2014-01-15 11:00:33.811 newUserInterface[1404:70b] CACurrentMediaTime:7201.885088
```

The result shows that if I add 5.0 on `beginTime`, the layer's time will minus 5.0. If an animation is in flight, adding 5.0 on `beginTime` will cause the animation redo the animation 5.0 seconds ago.

2、Assign 5.0 to layer's `timeOffset` (`timeOffset` is 0 before):

```
NSLog(@"CACurrentMediaTime:%f", [t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
t1.layer.timeOffset = 5.0 ;
NSLog(@"CACurrentMediaTime:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
```

result is:

```
2014-01-15 11:09:07.757 newUserInterface[1449:70b] CACurrentMediaTime:7720.851464
2014-01-15 11:09:07.758 newUserInterface[1449:70b] CACurrentMediaTime:7725.852011
```

The result shows that if I add 5.0 on `timeOffset`, the layer's time will add 5.0. If an animation is in flight, adding 5.0 on timeOffset will cause the animation jump to the animation it would do 5.0 seconds later.

**Comprehend pause and resume animation on a layer**

Here is an example, `t1` is an subview of UIViewController's root view. I do an animation on t1 which animates the position of `t1.layer`.

If an animation is added to a layer, the layer will calculate when to animate the animation according to the animation's `beginTime`, if the `beginTime` is 0, it will animate it immediately.

```
CABasicAnimation * b1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"] ;
b1.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(160.0, 320.0)] ;
b1.duration = 10.0f ;
[t1.layer addAnimation:b1 forKey:@"pos"] ;
NSLog(@"CACurrentMediaTime:%f", [t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
```

log shows `2014-01-15 11:25:53.975 newUserInterface[1530:70b] CACurrentMediaTime:8727.108740`, which means the animation will begin at 8727 and stop at 8727+10 in t1.layer's time space.

When the animation is in flight, and I pause the animation using `- (void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer` method.

`layer.speed = 0.0;` will cause the layer stop and layer's time will be set to 0. (I know that because when set layer.speed to 0, I immediately fetch the layer's time and log it)

`layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;` will add pauseTime to layer's time(assuming layer.timeOffset is 0), now the layer's time is pausedTime.

```
- (void)pauseLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]; // pauseTime is the time with respect to layer's time space
    layer.speed = 0.0; // layer's local time is 0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime; // layer's local time is pausedTime, so animation stop here
}
```

Then I will resume the animation using `- (void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer` method.

```
-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer {
   CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
   layer.speed = 1.0;
   layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
   layer.beginTime = 0.0;
   CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
   layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

If I stop the animation at 8727+1(means the animation animate for 1 second), in `pauseLayer` method, `layer.speed = 0` will set layer's time to 0 and `layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;` will add pausedTime on layer's time, so the layer's time is pausedTime.

Wait for a moment, let's have a summary now. `layer.speed` is 0.0, 'layer.timeOffset' is equal to `pausedTime` which is 8727+1 and layer's time is pausedTime too. Please keep in your mind, we will use them soon.

Let's continue, I resume the animation at 8727+11 with `resumeLayer` method, `layer.speed = 1.0;` it will add 8727+11 on layer's time, so layer's time is 8727+1+8727+11, `layer.timeOffset = 0.0;` it causes layer's time minus 8727+1 because layer.timeOffset is 8727+1 before, layer's local time is 8727+11 now. `timeSincePause` is (8727+11-8727-1)=10.

`layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;` it cause layer's time minus 10. Now layer's local time is 8727+1 which is the time I paused animation.

I will show you the code and log:

```
- (void)pauseLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    NSLog(@"%f", CACurrentMediaTime()) ;
    NSLog(@"pauseLayer begin:%f", [t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] ;
    layer.speed = 0.0 ;
    NSLog(@"pauseLayer after set speed to 0:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime ;
    NSLog(@"pauseLayer after set timeOffset:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
}

- (void)resumeLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    NSLog(@"%f", CACurrentMediaTime()) ;
    NSLog(@"resumeLayer begin:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = layer.timeOffset ;
    layer.speed = 1.0 ;
    NSLog(@"resumeLayer after set speed to 1:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    NSLog(@"resumeLayer after set timeOffset to 0:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0 ;
    NSLog(@"resumeLayer after set beginTime to 0:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime ;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause ;
    NSLog(@"resumeLayer after set beginTime to timeSincePause:%f",[t1.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]) ;
}
```

log:

```
2014-01-15 13:14:34.157 newUserInterface[1762:70b] 15247.550325
2014-01-15 13:14:34.158 newUserInterface[1762:70b] pauseLayer begin:15247.550826
2014-01-15 13:14:34.158 newUserInterface[1762:70b] pauseLayer after set speed to 0:0.000000
2014-01-15 13:14:34.159 newUserInterface[1762:70b] pauseLayer after set timeOffset:15247.551284

2014-01-15 13:14:40.557 newUserInterface[1762:70b] 15253.950505
2014-01-15 13:14:40.558 newUserInterface[1762:70b] resumeLayer begin:15247.551284
2014-01-15 13:14:40.558 newUserInterface[1762:70b] resumeLayer after set speed to 1:30501.502810
2014-01-15 13:14:40.559 newUserInterface[1762:70b] resumeLayer after set timeOffset to 0:15253.952031
2014-01-15 13:14:40.559 newUserInterface[1762:70b] resumeLayer after set beginTime to 0:15253.952523
2014-01-15 13:14:40.560 newUserInterface[1762:70b] resumeLayer after set beginTime to timeSincePause:15247.551294
```

Anther question is in `resumeLayer` method: why not combine the two assignment line to one `layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;`, the reason is in `[layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]`, the result value is related to layer.beginTime.

```
   layer.beginTime = 0.0;
   CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
   layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

Tell the truth, I still don't know how animation works behind, what I am doing is analyzing the result, it's not a good solution. I'm very glad that anyone who has ideas on this could share. Thanks!

Comment: @Unheilig No, assigning 10 to beginTime will cause layer's locale time reduce by 10. BTW I have updated my answer which is more clear.

Comment: @KudoCC thanks for sharing, I was struggling on the same topic, and I tried to adopt myself your same logging technic  at every step and I solved some animation problems I was having.

Comment: this is a fantastic explanation! I copied the logs and tried out, it became crystal clear. thanks @KudoCC. solved my problem.

Comment: How to stop the animation (pause+rewind) so it starts at time 0 at next resume?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/CAMediaTiming/beginTime):

> **beginTime**
>
> beginTime Specifies the begin time of the receiver in relation to its
> parent object, if applicable. (required)

Here's a great explanation of it taken from [here](http://wangling.me/2011/06/time-warp-in-animation.html):

> If an animation is in an animation group, beginTime is the offset from
> the beginning of its parent object — the animation group. So if
> beginTime of the animation is 5, it begins 5 seconds after the
> animation group begins.
>
> If an animation is added directly to a layer, beginTime is still the
> offset from the beginning of its parent object — the layer. But since
> the beginning of a layer is in the past1, I can not simply set
> beginTime to 5 to delay the animation 5 seconds, because 5 seconds
> after the beginning of a layer is probably still a past time. What I
> usually really want is a delay relative to when the animation is added
> to the layer — denoted by addTime.

This is the code from the question with an addition of logs:

```
- (IBAction)start:(UIButton *)sender
{    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^() {//Move square to x=300
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}

- (IBAction)pause:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
    NSLog(@"pausedTime: %f",pausedTime);
}

- (IBAction)resume:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    NSLog(@"CACurrentMediaTime: %f",[layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]);
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    NSLog(@"timeSincePause: %f",timeSincePause);
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

**Output:**

```
pausedTime: 20000
CACurrentMediaTime: 20005
timeSincePause: 5 // <- that's your begin time. When you hit resume you want to begin the animation from that relative time.
```

**To sum it all up,**

The animation duration is a total of 10, I stopped the animation at 5 and I also want it to be my beginTime when I resume the animation.

So, I save the pause time and subtract it from my current time in order to get the relative animation time that has passed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I think you missed some significant things. First, what you talked about is the beginTime of animation which added in group animation or add in layer, but what I want to know is the layer's beginTime. Second, In the `resume` method, it first `layer.beginTime = 0.0;` then `layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;`, why not assign layer.beginTime to  timeSincePause directly. I have comment out the `layer.beginTime = 0.0;`, but the animation is weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think the resume function only works for speed = 1, if speed is not equal 1 then the beginTime must be divided with speed to be corrected because beginTime is of type parent time, not line timeOffset that is local time.