# Start CABasicAnimation with an offset

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I'm having real trouble understanding the timing system of `CABasicAnimation`, especially the `beginTime` and `timeOffset` properties. I went through [this tutorial](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing) and questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946481/comprehend-pause-and-resume-animation-on-a-layer), which both explain a way of pausing/resuming animation. Still, I can't figure out how to **start an animation directly with an offset**.

I would like, for instance, to start my animation at 2.0s, meaning that if my animation is a color transition from white to black with a duration of 3.0s, then the animation would start from dark gray and transition to black in 1.0s.

I can't use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` because my animation is about changing the colors of a gradient (`CAGradientLayer`).

How can I start my animation with the offset I want, when I add it to a layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a `CABasicAnimation` directly with an offset, it's as simple as setting its `timeOffset` to the time within the animation's timeline you want it to start.

So for example, if your animation's `duration` is set to 3, and the `timeOffset` is set to 2, then the animation will (visibly) begin at 2 seconds into the animation.

However, this does not stop the animation from then wrapping back around to finish the part of the animation that was skipped (from 0-2 seconds). If you want the animation to stop after it gets to its `toValue`, you can set `repeatDuration` to 1 to cut off the animation after 1 second.

Here's a complete Playground example where you can play around with the animation properties and click on the live view to see the animation:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class GradientView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override var layer: CAGradientLayer {
        super.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        layer.locations = [0, 1]

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                         action: #selector(animateGradient))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }

    @objc func animateGradient() {

        // Animate the `colors` property of the gradient layer.
        // In this example we're just animating the first color of
        // a two-color gradient.
        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
        anim.fromValue = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        anim.toValue = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]

        // Sets the length of the animation's timeline.
        //
        // Note that in this case, this is not the _effective_ duration
        // as we are stopping the animation after 1 second due to setting
        // `repeatDuration` below.
        anim.duration = 3

        // Where in the animation's timeline the animation should
        // effectively start.
        //
        // In this case, this starts the animation 2 seconds in to the
        // timeline, which makes it look like the first gradient color
        // immediately starts at dark gray.
        anim.timeOffset = 2

        // Stops the animation when it gets to the `toValue`.
        // This makes the effective duration 1 second long.
        //
        // Comment this out to let the animation loop back around
        // so that it then fades from white to dark gray, if desired.
        anim.repeatDuration = anim.duration - anim.timeOffset

        layer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    }
}

let gradientViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = GradientView(frame: gradientViewFrame)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! My problem was that I was reusing the animation object I already used for another view, thus the `timeOffset` property was not working. Creating a new animation and copying the values worked, with your implementation.

Comment: Ace. This is the only answer I've found that used the repeatDuration variable.